# How to read raw files in a generic manner (little/big endian)?

Tags: file, generics, architecture, endianness

I am writing a `RawFile` class in C++ (the language does not matter here). But, I would like to keep the library totally generic whatever the CPU it is compiled for.

For now, I have a `uint16_t swap16(uint16_t value)` function which swap the two bytes and return an unsigned integer and a `bool is_bigendian()` function which return `true` if the system is in big-endian and `false` otherwise (I decided to ignore the PDP-11 byte-ordering scheme as it is very unlikely encountered). Finally, I have the endianness of the raw file that I am reading.

The question is as follow, given the information of the endianness of the file and the system, how can I decide if I apply the `swap16()` function?

For now, I decided to use the following test:

```
return (file_is_big_endian || system_is_big_endian) ? swap16(value) : value;
```

I assumed the following table:

```
sytem\rawfile | little-endian | big-endian |
--------------------------------------------
little-endian |   No swap16() |  swap16()  |
   big-endian |    swap16()   |  swap16()  |
```

But, I am not really sure if this is correct, I might be missing something.

Any good explanations (or better tests) are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question...

In fact, I realized that I was reading the file byte per byte (in a "raw mode"). So, the fact that the system itself is little-endian or big-endian is just irrelevant. You just have to consider the type of the file you read to reorder (or not) the set of bytes you are reading... So, the test is simply:

```
return (file_is_big_endian) ? swap16(value) : value;
```

Probably just a stupid question...